# Can I draw a superhero comic that revolves around a Muslim?

Tags: halal-haram

The whole story is based around a Muslim hero that struggles and shows the world control, compassion, divinity, respect in a world full of greed , war and normal superhero stuff.

No nudity or sexual content. All women dressed appropriately. I won’t be forcing religions. There will be subtle mentions etc..

It’s for pure fun and hopefully knowledge.

So in this case would drawing it be halal? 
Like any normal superhero comic book.

Comment: I think the question revolves around the idea if you can draw faces of living creatures. My take on the matter is if the faces are drawn in a way that is not realistic, then I guess it's fine. If body parts are drawn rather than faces as a whole, then it's alright. And Allah knows best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assallmu-Alaykam,
   Regardless of the intention drawing animate being with souls will always be frowned on

Aishah (May Allah be pleased with her) said: The Messenger of Allah (sallallaahu ’alayhi wa sallam) visited me after returning from a journey, and I had a shelf with a thin cloth curtain hanging over it and on which there were portraits. When he saw it, the colour of his face changed (because of anger) and he said, "O Aishah! the most grievous torment from Allah on the Day of Resurrection will be for those who imitate (Allah) in the act of His creation.'' `Aishah said: We tore it into pieces and made a cushion or two cushions out of that. [Al-Bukhari and Muslim].

However, drawing things that have no soul such as trees and fruit are permissable.

Comment: What if I draw a comic with head not connected to the body?